# How do i add icons on the woocommerce tabs in the my account page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, divi-theme

I'm trying to add in the Woocommerce my account page on the tab navigation some icons.
**Like this:** https://woocommerce.files.wordpress.com/2016/04/storefront-2-my-account.png?w=1224
I've tried some tutorials but no luck. Using the Divi theme form elegantthemes. Does anyone have the solution?

Comment: This can be done with CSS very easy. But it's a problem to submit a proper solution without any reference. Try to share a link, or the html structure of this specific elements here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On WooCommerce My Account page on the tab navigation icons has been added through CSS pseudo-element.

```
.woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation ul li.woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link--YOUR-PAGE a::before
```

Comment: If you use font-awesome here's the tutorial https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements

Answer (score 3):

To add custom HTML to the tab title you can create an array from your icons and change **nvaigation.php** in the **woocommerce template folder** like below:

```
$icons = [
    'dashboard' => '<i class="icon-dashboard"></i>',
    'orders' => '<i class="icon-orders"></i>',
    'edit-account' => '<i class="icon-edit-account"></i>',
    'customer-logout' => '<i class="icon-customer-logout"></i>',
    'downloads' => '<i class="icon-downloads"></i>',
    'edit-address' => '<i class="icon-edit-address"></i>'
];
```

and in the **foreach** of rendering tabs echo with **$endpoint** like below:

```
<?php foreach ( wc_get_account_menu_items() as $endpoint => $label ) : ?>
  <a class="<?php echo wc_get_account_menu_item_classes( $endpoint ); ?>" href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_account_endpoint_url( $endpoint ) ); ?>">
    <?php echo $icons[$endpoint] ?>
    <?php echo esc_html( $label ); ?>
  </a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

with this method, you can add any content to your tabs

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code as an example to change the account icon.

Change the -dashboard for the tab link and icon Unicode like f4fe

```
.woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation ul li.woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link--dashboard a:before {
    content: "\f4fe";
}
```